# RecyclerView is being displayed on ConstraintLayout 2.0.0-beta7, but 1.1.3

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack

I have a RecyclerView within a ConstraintLayout. Everything gets displayed and works ok.

The problem is that the performance is really bad on 2.0.0-beta7, so I decided to downgrade it to a stable version, which is 1.1.3. The performance is incredibly great, but the problem now is that the recyclerView is not being displayed.

The recyclerView has a wrap_content height, but when checked on Layout Inspector, it says 0. Am I missing something?

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
        tools:listitem="@layout/radio_button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things we tend to miss out while using `ConstraintLayout`. One of them is using `0dp` when apt and another is giving constraints to almost all the directions.

You have not given any constraint to the bottom of your view.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_layout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/radio_button" />
```

In case you want your recycler view to be in the center of `toolbar_layout` and parent bottom, you can remove `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"`. In case you want your recycler view to stick to the bottom of the parent, you can change the value of the bias to "1.0".

Also, make sure that you are using the correct `orientation`. If the orientation is supposed to be `horizontal`, you might want to change the width of your layout to `0dp` or `match_parent`.

Comment: You are right. In my case, I needed to downgrade the library (do not use beta) and use `0dp` as height and width. Also, is not constraint to the bottom because the bottom view is constrained to top and bottom. Because if I constraint them all top and bottom, will display warning.